# Playing a sequence of sounds without gaps (iPhone)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio

I thought maybe the fastest way was to go with Sound Services. It is quite efficient, but I need to play sounds in a sequence, not overlapped. Therefore I used a callback method to check when the sound has finished. This cycle produces around 0.3 seconds in lag. I know this sounds very strict, but it is basically the main axis of the program.

EDIT: I now tried using `AVAudioPlayer`, but I can't play sounds in a sequence without using `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` since that would put me in the same situation as with the callback method of SoundServices.

EDIT2: I think that if I could somehow get to join the parts of the sounds I want to play into a large file, I could get the whole audio file to sound continuously.

EDIT3: I thought this would work, but the audio overlaps:

```
waitTime = player.deviceCurrentTime;

    for (int k = 0; k < [colores count]; k++)
    {    
        player.currentTime = 0;
        [player playAtTime:waitTime];
        waitTime += player.duration;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried a technique that I think will work well for you.  Build an audio file with your sounds concatenated.  Then build some meta data about your sounds like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *soundData;
@synthesize soundData=_soundData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _soundData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *sound = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil];
    [self.soundData setValue:sound forKey:@"soundA"];
    sound = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:6.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil];
    [self.soundData setValue:sound forKey:@"soundB"];
    sound = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:7.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil];
    [self.soundData setValue:sound forKey:@"soundC"];
}
```

The first number is the offset of the sound in the file, the second is the duration.  Then get your player ready to play like this...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);              
    else {
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

Then you can build a low-level sound playing method like this ...

```
- (void)playSound:(NSString *)name withCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion {

    NSArray *sound = [self.soundData valueForKey:name];
    if (!sound) return;

    NSTimeInterval offset = [[sound objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[sound objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

    audioPlayer.currentTime = offset;
    [audioPlayer play];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        [audioPlayer pause];
        completion();
    });
}
```

And you can play sounds in rapid combination like this ...

```
- (IBAction)playAB:(id)sender {

    [self playSound:@"soundA" withCompletion:^{
        [self playSound:@"soundB" withCompletion:^{}];
    }];
}
```

Rather than nesting blocks, you could build a higher-level method that takes a list of sound names and plays them one after the other, that would look like this:

```
- (void)playSoundList:(NSArray *)soundNames withCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion {

    if (![soundNames count]) return completion();

    NSString *firstSound = [soundNames objectAtIndex:0];
    NSRange remainingRange = NSMakeRange(1, [soundNames count]-1);
    NSArray *remainingSounds = [soundNames subarrayWithRange:remainingRange];

    [self playSound:firstSound withCompletion:^{
        [self playSoundList:remainingSounds withCompletion:completion];
    }];
}
```

Call it like this...

```
NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"soundB", @"soundC", @"soundA", nil];
[self playSoundList:list withCompletion:^{ NSLog(@"done"); }];
```

Comment: Is there some way to put `[self playSound:@"soundName" withCompletion:^{}]` inside a for? I have an array with the notes I want to play, but I don't see how I can input the value from the array into the method. I guess I have to execute that method in pairs, right? Assign the box 0 of the array to method 1, box 1, to method 2; assign box 3 to method 1, box 4 to method 2 and so on, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to change the sequence or omit sounds sometimes.  (Otherwise you would just build the asset with all three sounds in a row and play that).

There might be a better idea out there, but to get things very tight, you could consider producing that concatenated asset, pre-loading it - moving up all the latency to that one load, then seeking around it to change the sound.

Comment: The problem is that there might be around 600 sounds. I don't think I can preload 600 `AVAudioPlayer`s.

Comment: Are they short?  You would create a single player and preload a single combined asset.  You would also load 600 time offsets in a dictionary.  To play a sound, you would lookup the sound name and seek to that offset.  Seek and play is fast.  Load is slow, but you would do that in advance.

Comment: How do I load in advance while the player is playing? Or how do I load all the audio files? [Like this as is "Preparing an Asset for Use"?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html)

Comment: I was thinking simpler - at compile time, using any tools you choose build a combined audio file.  At launch time, build an AVAudioPlayer and get it ready to play.  Then call playAtTime (with a timer that expires at the duration of that sound).  You could build a little class that takes a list of sound names, looks up their locations (time offsets) and durations, sets a timer for the first duration, playAtTime: for the first offset, when timer expires, do the same for the second, and so on.  I think the seek in an already loaded single file will be quick.

Comment: I might try this myself for fun this weekend.  If I get something useful, I'll post here.

Comment: I tried using the Audio Player, but for some reason it plays only once inside a for. This is the code: `for(int k = 0; k < k < 600; k++)
    {
        [player playAtTime:0.0625];
    }`

Comment: Okay, I guess the program doesn't wait for [player play] to end. Is there some way to stop the program while player is playing sound?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I think you would need to know durations and set a timer (see NSTimer, or performSelector:afterDelay:).

Comment: Forgot.  But I did it just now.  Will add a new answer.